# Installing hunspell package

Tags: python, centos7, hunspell

I'm looking forward to install the hunspell package using pip, but it throws the following error:

```
Collecting hunspell
  Using cached hunspell-0.4.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: hunspell
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for hunspell ... error
  Complete output from command /root/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-oyfpp3iy/hunspell/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmphqvqt4lxpip-wheel- --python-tag cp34:
  /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/distutils/extension.py:132: UserWarning: Unknown Extension options: 'compile_args', 'macros'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'hunspell' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
  gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/hunspell -I/root/anaconda3/include/python3.4m -c hunspell.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/hunspell.o
  hunspell.c:21:22: erreur fatale: hunspell.h : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
   #include <hunspell.h>
                        ^
  compilation terminée.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for hunspell
  Running setup.py clean for hunspell
Failed to build hunspell
Installing collected packages: hunspell
  Running setup.py install for hunspell ... error
    Complete output from command /root/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-oyfpp3iy/hunspell/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-euhsmasb-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/distutils/extension.py:132: UserWarning: Unknown Extension options: 'compile_args', 'macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'hunspell' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/hunspell -I/root/anaconda3/include/python3.4m -c hunspell.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/hunspell.o
    hunspell.c:21:22: erreur fatale: hunspell.h : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
     #include <hunspell.h>
                          ^
    compilation terminée.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/root/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-oyfpp3iy/hunspell/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-euhsmasb-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-oyfpp3iy/hunspell/
[root@localhost Bureau]# alias python-devel=python34-devel
[root@localhost Bureau]# pip install hunspell
Collecting hunspell
  Using cached hunspell-0.4.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: hunspell
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for hunspell ... error
  Complete output from command /root/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-xpljhkom/hunspell/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmptwg_9c8vpip-wheel- --python-tag cp34:
  /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/distutils/extension.py:132: UserWarning: Unknown Extension options: 'compile_args', 'macros'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'hunspell' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
  gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/hunspell -I/root/anaconda3/include/python3.4m -c hunspell.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/hunspell.o
  hunspell.c:21:22: erreur fatale: hunspell.h : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
   #include <hunspell.h>
                        ^
  compilation terminée.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for hunspell
  Running setup.py clean for hunspell
Failed to build hunspell
Installing collected packages: hunspell
  Running setup.py install for hunspell ... error
    Complete output from command /root/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-xpljhkom/hunspell/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-zrlp2go9-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/distutils/extension.py:132: UserWarning: Unknown Extension options: 'compile_args', 'macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'hunspell' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/hunspell -I/root/anaconda3/include/python3.4m -c hunspell.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/hunspell.o
    hunspell.c:21:22: erreur fatale: hunspell.h : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
     #include <hunspell.h>
                          ^
    compilation terminée.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/root/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-xpljhkom/hunspell/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-zrlp2go9-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-xpljhkom/hunspell/
```

And I've heard that installing python3-dev would resolve the problem.
I tried with no succes.
I'm using python 3.4 under CentOS 7.
Can I get some help please ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show full log of error please.

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 8):

I just went through this using python3.4 and pip3.4 on Centos7 64-bit. (NB you need both python3.4 and pip3.4)

I eventually got it working via pip3.4, but before this would work, I had to take a few extra steps. The steps I took were:

Install the python3.4 development headers:

```
sudo yum install python34u-devel.x86_64
```

Install hunspell and hunspell-devel (needed for hunspell.h and hunspell lib):

```
sudo yum install hunspell hunspell-devel
```

In /usr/lib64/, add an extra symlink for the hunspell library:

```
sudo ln -s libhunspell-1.3.so libhunspell.so
```

Finally, run the command:

```
sudo pip3.4 install hunspell
```

... and this gave me the following output:

```
... (compiler output deleted) ...
Successfully built hunspell
Installing collected packages: hunspell
Successfully installed hunspell-0.4.1
```

Answer (score 5):

Try This:

```
sudo apt install python-dev libhunspell-dev
pip install hunspell
```

Comment: For python3 I used: `sudo apt install python3-dev libhunspell-dev` and `pip3 install hunspell`.

Answer (score 2):

*Solution by OP.*

I figured it out, I'll share this method here, it may help :)
first you need to install python-devel and

```
yum install python-devel  
yum install hunspell-devel
```

then corrected your symlink

```
cd /usr/lib64
sudo ln -s libhunspell-1.3.so.0.0.0 libhunspell.so
ls -l | grep hunspell
```

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 1):

I am working on MAC OS and this solved the error for me.

Hunspell Installation Steps:

```
brew install hunspell (installed version 1.7.0_2-1)
brew install pkg-config (0.29.2_3)
ln -s /usr/local/lib/libhunspell-1.7.a /usr/local/lib/libhunspell.a
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/hunspell/1.7.0_2/lib/libhunspell-1.7.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/hunspell/1.7.0_2/lib/libhunspell.dylib
CFLAGS=$(pkg-config --cflags hunspell) LDFLAGS=$(pkg-config --libs hunspell) pip3 install hunspell
```