# Unable to install hunspell library (python 3.9) on mac m1

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew

I am using python 3.9 and macOS Big Sur with an m1 chip. I have been trying to use spell checking library (hunspell) in python for spelling correction. While following their official documentation from https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell I am getting the following error after `pip install hunspell` :

```
Complete output (12 lines):
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'hunspell' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/shahzainmehboob/miniforge3/envs/tensorflow/include -arch arm64 -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/shahzainmehboob/miniforge3/envs/tensorflow/include -arch arm64 -D_LINUX -I/usr/local/Cellar/hunspell/1.6.2/include/hunspell -I/Users/shahzainmehboob/miniforge3/envs/tensorflow/include/python3.9 -c hunspell.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/hunspell.o -Wall
hunspell.cpp:20:10: fatal error: 'hunspell.hxx' file not found
#include <hunspell.hxx>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
```

I have followed the issue [Installing hunspell package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756466/installing-hunspell-package) and the answer from @Suraj Rao:

`brew install hunspell (installed version 1.7.0_2-1) brew install pkg-config (0.29.2_3) ln -s /usr/local/lib/libhunspell-1.7.a /usr/local/lib/libhunspell.a ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/hunspell/1.7.0_2/lib/libhunspell-1.7.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/hunspell/1.7.0_2/lib/libhunspell.dylib CFLAGS=$(pkg-config --cflags hunspell) LDFLAGS=$(pkg-config --libs hunspell) pip3 install hunspell`

but I am still not able to find the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when trying to install [cython_hunspell](https://github.com/MSeal/cython_hunspell).

I had to first clone it, then install locally for it to work properly :

```
git clone https://github.com/MSeal/cython_hunspell.git
cd cython_hunspell
pip install .
```

You can test it works properly :

```
cd ..
python -c "from hunspell import Hunspell; h = Hunspell(); print(h.spell('correct')); print(h.spell('incorect'))"
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you make sure to install gcc by using `brew install gcc` command. After that you can use `brew install hunspell` command for installation.

Comment: Didn't help. The problem isn't with `gcc`, it look like an issue with the path of the file...